# How to extend Euler's identity regarding partition on the unit disk?

Tags: proof-writing, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions

> > **Theorem** (Euler) $:$ For $|x|<1$ we have
> >
> > $$\prod\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {1-x^m} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n) x^n,$$ where $p(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ for $n \geq 1$ and $p(0)=1.$

In my book the above identity is proved only for $0 \leq x < 1$ and it was said at the end of the proof that this proof can be extended analytically to the whole unit disk. But how do I do that? Would anybody please help me regarding this?

What I have understood is that if I can show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac {p(n+1)} {p(n)} = 1$ then I am done. But I can't able to find the limit. Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which book${{}}$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown the book is T.M. Apostol's Analytic Number Theory; page no. 310.

Comment: That the LHS converges for $|x| < 1$ implies so does the RHS. Alternatively since $p(n) \ge 0$ that the RHS converges for $ x=r$ implies it converges for $|x| \le r$. Once both side converge the proof they are equal is the same for $x > 0$ or not.

Comment: But before that we need to ensure whether LHS is indeed equal to RHS or not. The book only provides a rigorous proof of the above equality whenever $0 \leq x < 1.$ So my question is how do I extend this equality to the unit disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216773/clarification-of-the-proof-of-eulers-identity-regarding-the-generating-function?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6618114_3216773), it is easy to prove this using the fact that [uniformly converging analytic functions converge to analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_analyticity).

We have [uniform convergence of an infinite product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239423) easily here on any disk of radius $r<1$ since

$$\left|\log\left[\frac1{1-z^m}\right]\right|=|\log(1-z^m)|\le|z|^m+\frac{|z|^{2m}}{|1-z^m|^2}\le r^m+\frac{r^{2m}}{1-r^m}$$

which converges by the ratio test for all $r\in[0,1)$.

Thus, the LHS is analytic on $|z|<1$.

Similarly for the RHS, we have the simple bound:

$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)z^n\right|\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)|z|^n\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)r^n$$

The convergence of the last sum is also very likely proven in your book for $r\in[0,1)$.

Thus, the RHS is analytic on $|z|<1$.

Thus it follows from a simple analytic continuation argument that this holds for all $|z|<1$.

Comment: How do you get the inequality @Simply Beautiful Art $$|\log (1-z^m)| \leq |z|^m + \frac {|z|^{2m}} {|1-z^m|^2}$$?

Comment: From Taylor's theorem.