# Clarification of the proof of Euler's identity regarding the generating function for partitions.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions, analytic-continuation

In reference to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214764/598690) which I asked here couple  of days back but didn't get any answer I am posting this question to clarify whether we can able to extend Euler's identity regarding the generating function for partitions to the unit disk from the interval $[0,1).$ I think that I need to take help of analytic continuation. But for that I need to show that the function $F(x)= \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {1 - x^k}$ is analytic on the unit disk and the function $G(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} p(k)x^k$ is analytic on $[0,1).$  If they are so then we say that $F$ is an analytic continuation of $G$ on the unit disk. Then only we can say that $G$ can be extended analytically to the unit disk and for all $x \in S^1 \setminus [0,1)$ we assign $G(x)= F(x).$ That will do my job.  But why $F$ and $G$ are analytic in their respective domains. Can anybody please  help  me regarding this?

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Both sides are holomorphic, since they are uniformly convergent on each closed disc $\{z:|z|\le r\}$ for $r<1$.

Comment: Why is it so @Lord Shark the Unknown? Would you please be more explicit about your argument?